# Fiscal printers not receiving commands

Tags: php, printing, escpos, fiscal-printer

I have a thermal printer`(DATECS FP-700CRX)`... and it only prints using commands.

I've used several printing drivers including `Mike42/escpos-php` drivers but still can't get anything out from the printer.

Even a simple `Hello World` text receipt is failing to be printed.
anyone to help resolve the issue, even just printing a simple `Hello World` text.

I've tried several codes and the recent one is below, but nothing shows up.

Am using `RS232` serial port:

````
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;

$connector = new FilePrintConnector("COM9");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> text("Hello World\n");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();```
````

Comment: Is it necessary to work with a Fiscal printer according to some usage procedure such as the Fiscal law of the target country? General-purpose / free / open source libraries such as escpos-php should be used after confirming that they comply with the Fiscal law.

Comment: Thanks Richard.... All laws to observe the fiscal tax laws are being followed, and the printer has already been fiscalised. But the issue is to print out using commands which is not working.                                                                     The printer has certain commands using an executable application it is able to print out certain information but I need a way to print the same commands using my application and can't find a way out

Comment: If you look at the specifications tab on this page, it says `Datecs Proprietary Fiscal Protocol`, so you need to get the programming manual, SDK, etc.? [FP-700 | DATECS LTD](https://www.datecs.bg/en/products/47) If you're following along, only the printer vendor's support desk will know what's wrong. Please ask there.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the fiscal protocol, that could be the starting point of making my way out..........

Comment: It could be explained by the target country's government, tax officials and printer vendors. I only comment with general shallow knowledge and have no knowledge or experience with such Fiscal protocols.